# Postgres default privileges for readonly role

Tags: database, postgresql

I have created a PostgreSQL (version 11.5) database and I want to create two different types of main roles (`readonly` and `readwrite`) and then assign these roles to individuals (`user1`, `user2`, etc.).

I have been reading the PostgreSQL documentation and following this article as an example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/

**However, I have not been able to get the permissions set correctly.  Basically, I want the role `readwrite` to be able to create any schema and/or tables they want within this database, and I want the role `readonly` to be able to `SELECT` from any of the schemas and/or tables in this database.  However, following my example below, `user2` can create a table, but `user1` does not have access to that table.**

I have created the following script that I can run as the master user for the database to create the database, schema, and roles.

### Command to run SQL script:

```
psql -h <INSERT HOST HERE> -U postgres -W -f create_db.sql
```

### Contents of create_db.sql

```
-- drop the existing database
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS new_db;

-- create the database
CREATE DATABASE new_db;

-- connect to the database
\c new_db

-- create the new schema
CREATE SCHEMA new_schema;

-- revoke privileges from 'public' role
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE new_db FROM PUBLIC;

-- create readonly role
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS readonly;
CREATE ROLE readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE new_db TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA new_schema TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA new_schema TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA new_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;

-- create read/write role
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS readwrite;
CREATE ROLE readwrite;
GRANT CONNECT, CREATE ON DATABASE new_db TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA new_schema TO readwrite;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA new_schema TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA new_schema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA new_schema TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA new_schema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO readwrite;

-- create users
DROP USER IF EXISTS user1;
DROP USER IF EXISTS user2;
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE USER user2 WITH PASSWORD 'password';

-- grant privileges to users
GRANT readonly TO user1;
GRANT readwrite TO user2;
```

After the script successfully runs, I can run the following script as `user2` to create a table in the new schema.

### Command to run SQL script

```
psql -h <INSERT HOST HERE> -d new_db -U user2 -W -f create_.sql
```

### Contents of create_table.sql

```
-- drop the existing table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_schema.new_table;

-- create a new table
CREATE TABLE new_schema.new_table (name VARCHAR, age INT);

-- insert data into the new table
INSERT INTO new_schema.new_table (name, age) VALUES ('Bob', 42);
```

Now, if `user1` (readonly) logs into the database, I would hope they would be able to `SELECT` from this newly created table, however, it appears they do not have the correct access. They are able to see the table, but not query it.

```
psql -h <INSERT HOST HERE> -d new_db -U user1 -W
```

```
new_db=> \dt new_schema.*
           List of relations
   Schema   |   Name    | Type  | Owner 
------------+-----------+-------+-------
 new_schema | new_table | table | user2
(1 row)

new_db=> SELECT * FROM new_schema.new_table;
ERROR:  permission denied for table new_table
```

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL 11.7 it works with the following modifications:

1. either the newly created table must be created by *postgres* user
2. or running `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA new_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;` must be run by *user2*.

For example if I run create_table.sql as user2 with the above modification:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA new_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES

CREATE TABLE new_schema.new_table (name VARCHAR, age INT);
CREATE TABLE

INSERT INTO new_schema.new_table (name, age) VALUES ('Bob', 42);
INSERT 0 1

$ psql -U user1 -d new_db
psql (11.7)
Type "help" for help.

new_db=> select * from new_schema.new_table;
 name | age 
------+-----
 Bob  |  42
(1 row)


new_db=> \dp+ new_schema.new_table;
                                  Access privileges
   Schema   |   Name    | Type  |  Access privileges  | Column privileges | Policies 
------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+-------------------+----------
 new_schema | new_table | table | readonly=r/user2   +|                   | 
            |           |       | user2=arwdDxt/user2 |                   | 
(1 row)
```

I understand that ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES must be run by the owner of the future involved objects.

Comment: That's interesting that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` must be run by the owner of the future objects.  I was hoping that I could run that as the master postgres user, and then it would be set for all roles and tables now and in the future.